# Ember.js: Accessing parent route's controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Users in my app have profile pages. User can view his own profile and profiles of other users. On his own profile he is able to change his avatar, but of course he can't change avatar of another user. Script for avatar uploading is loaded on demand, using profile route's `beforeModel` hook. The problem is to load this script only when user visits his own profile, not profiles of other users.

Here is my code:

**Router:**

```
Router.map(function () {

    this.resource('user', { path: '/:user_id' }, function () {
        this.resource('profile');
    });

});
```

**Application route:**

```
var ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({

    model: function () {
        return {
            currentUser: this.config.currentUser
        };
    }

});
```

**User route:**

```
var UserRoute = Em.Route.extend({

    model: function (params) {
        var currentUser = this.modelFor('application').get('currentUser');

        if (currentUser.get('id') === params.user_id) {
            return currentUser;
        } else {
            // getUser returns promise
            return this.data.getUser(params.user_id);
        }
    }

});
```

**User controller:**

```
var UserController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

    needs: 'application',

    isCurrent: function () {
        return (this.get('id') === this.get('controllers.application.currentUser.id'));
    }.property('id')

});
```

**Profile route:**

```
var uploaderScriptInjected = false;

var ProfileRoute = Em.Route.extend({

    beforeModel: function () {
        if (!uploaderScriptInjected && this.uploaderNeeded()) {
            return $.getScript(this.config.assets.uploader)
                .then(function () {
                    uploaderScriptInjected = true;
                });
        }
    },

    uploaderNeeded: function () {
        // This is not working:

        // return this.controllerFor('user').get('isCurrent');
    },

    model: function () {
        var user = this.modelFor('user');

        return Em.RSVP.hash({
            photos: this.data.photosByUser(user.get('id'))
        });
    }

});
```

Take a look at `beforeModel` and `uploaderNeeded` methods of profile route. I want to use `isCurrent` property of user controller, but `setupController` method of user route is called **after** `uploaderNeeded`, which means that the instance of user controller hasn't been generated and the model for it hasn't been set. Of course I could use this code:

```
uploaderNeeded: function () {
    return this.modelFor('application').get('currentUser.id') === this.modelFor('user').get('id');
}
```

...but it repeats `isCurrent` property logic of user controller.

Is there any way to access user controller's properties from profile route's methods?

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend parent controller for example
`App.FirstController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({})`
and then 
`App.SecondController = Ember.FirstController.extend({})`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how can it help me?

Comment: You can make Profile controller that extend UserController .. this must work but i am not sure